# Can I use Azure AD "businessPhones" in a URL parameter?

Tags: url, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, url-parameters

I am able to use a number of Azure AD profile entity fields in a URL parameter for parsing the logged in user's profile data into a form on our intranet for pre-fill or the like.
For example, `...URL?officelocation=(user.apiProfile.officeLocation)&fullname=(user.fullName)&email=(user.email)&jobtitle=(user.apiProfile.jobTitle)`.
All of these fields are single string data types according to https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users/$entity.

I'd like to know if it's possible to use the first or second value of a collection of strings as a parameter in the URL. And if so, how?

Take the "businessPhones" field for example.  I've tried using `&userphone=(user.businessPhones[0])` or other formations but am unable to return the field data.

On a page of our intranet which uses Azure AD as the Identity Provider via SAML 2.0 and uses the Microsoft Graph API, I am able to surface almost any user profile data dynamically on the page as content -  including those fields which are in an array (or collection of strings), using the below script and html snippet as example.

```html
<p>First name + Last name:&nbsp;<span id="user-firstname" style="font-weight:600;"></span> <span id="user-lastname" style="font-weight:600;"></span></p>

<p>Full name:&nbsp;<span id="user-fullname" style="font-weight:600;"></span></p>

<p>Email address:&nbsp;<span id="user-email" style="font-weight:600;"></span></p>

<p>Job title:&nbsp;<span id="user-jobtitle" style="font-weight:600;"></span></p>

<p>Office Phone:&nbsp;<span id="user-officephone" style="font-weight:600;"></span></p>

<p>Firm Name:&nbsp;<span id="user-firm" style="font-weight:600;"></span></p>

<p>Firm Address:&nbsp;<!--<span id="user-streetaddress" style="font-weight:600;"></span> <span id="user-city" style="font-weight:600;"></span>,&nbsp;<span id="user-postcode" style="font-weight:600;"></span>,&nbsp;--><span id="user-state" style="font-weight:600;"></span></p>

<p>UID:&nbsp;<span id="user-id" style="font-weight:600;"></span></p>

<p>Embedded Page:&nbsp;<a href="#" id="current-url"><span id="text-url" style="font-weight:600;"></span></a></p>

<script>
    $('#user-firstname').html(CONNECTED_USER.firstName);
    $('#user-lastname').html(CONNECTED_USER.lastName);
    $('#user-fullname').html(CONNECTED_USER.fullName);
    $('#user-email').html(CONNECTED_USER.email);
    $('#user-jobtitle').html(CONNECTED_USER.apiProfile.jobTitle);
    $('#user-officephone').html(CONNECTED_USER.apiProfile.phones[1].value);
    $('#user-firm').html(CONNECTED_USER.apiProfile.officeLocation);
    /*$('#user-streetaddress').html(CONNECTED_USER.apiProfile.streetAddress);*/
    /*$('#user-city').html(CONNECTED_USER.apiProfile.city);*/
    /*$('#user-postcode').html(CONNECTED_USER.apiProfile.postalCode);*/
    $('#user-state').html(CONNECTED_USER.apiProfile.organizations[0].stateLocation);
    $('#user-id').html(CONNECTED_USER.id);
    $('#user-url').html(CONNECTED_USER.url);
    $('#current-url').attr("href", window.location.href);
    $('#text-url').html(window.location.href)

</script>
```

You can see that I use `CONNECTED_USER.apiProfile.phones[1].value` and `CONNECTED_USER.apiProfile.organizations[0].stateLocation` to return the data I wish to show.

Is it possible to do similar with URL parameters?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's based on which language you used for composing the url. For example, in asp.net core, when you got the response from graph api, you can see that the `BusinessPhones` property is `IEnumerable<string>`, so you can't use `user.businessPhones[0]` but `BusinessPhones.FirstOrDefault()`.

And if you compose the url in javascript, it should work when you use `user.businessPhones[0]`, if it doesn't work, you may add `console.log(user.businessPhones)` to see the data.

By the way if some users has no value for `businessPhones` property, you may need to consider it.